# Redux-saga yield put() in catch block not executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Really odd issue I am having. For some reason my `put` in my `catch` block is not being executed below. Here's my saga:

```
function* postLoginFormSaga(action) {
    let response;
    try {
        // Data from emitting login action
        response = yield call(AuthenticationApi.login, action.formData);
        yield put(createLoginSucceedAction());
        yield put(push('/dashboard/summary'));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        yield put(createLoginFailAction(response))
    }
}
```

And my api call, which has a custom middleware to handle non `2XX` responses:

```
static login = (formData) => {
        return fetch('/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        }).then(handleFetchErrorMiddleWare)
            .then(r => r.json())
    };
```

Where the middleware function is a simple function that checks the `ok` property of the `response` object:

```
export function handleFetchErrorMiddleWare(response) {
    if (!response.ok){
        throw Error(response.status)
    }
    return response
}
```

The middleware is working correctly as I can see the output of the `console.log(e)` when an exception is thrown, but the `yield put(createLoginFailAction(response))` is not being emitted ...
See below:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is it correct `yield put(createLoginFailAction(response))`? `response` is `undefined` here.

Comment: There could be an error in the `createLoginFailAction` function, what does that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like there is an error in the `createLoginFailAction` function, if so that would cause the result that you are seeing.